# How to query for getting value from either Table A or B?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, purchase-order

This is Datagridview which I need to display on the screen like these.
(Datagrid view is binding with the **"main table" (RECEIVE_PLAN)**)

[image]

**Concept Design database:**

if you want to import something into warehouse, you must plan for receiving in a day.
Receiving Plan is made from "Purchase Order" directly
**Or** sometime your warehouse has a receiving schedule before ordering.

Database has three tables, including **Table A** and **Table B** and **Main Table**.

They have  a relation like these.

**Note:** the main table has two options for getting value for display to the screen

1. get **"PO_LIST_NO"** and **"PO_NO"** from **A table**(PURCHASE ORDER table) directly.
2. get **"PO_LIST_NO"** and **"PO_NO"** from **B table**(RECEIVE SCHEDULE table) then get value from A table.
   [image]

**Important Conditions**

1. In main table (RECEIVE PLAN) must have a value in either "PO_ID" or "RS_ID"
2. If main table (RECEIVE PLAN) has a value at PO_ID column, RS_ID column must be NULL.
   On the other hand,  If main table (RECEIVE PLAN) has a value at
   RS_ID column, PO_ID column must be NULL
3. Main Table (RECEIVE PLAN) must not NULL both PO_ID and RS_ID
4. Main Table (RECEIVE PLAN) must not has a value at both PO_ID and RS_ID

**RECEIVE PLAN's example like below.**

[image]

(PO_TRAN_ID) is PO_ID

(RS_TRAN_ID) is RS_ID in this case.

**QUESTION :How to query for getting value from  either Table A or B?**

How to join between a **main table**,**A** and **B table** for display like these.

[image]

This datagridview Properties.

**BindingSource :** main table (RECEIVE_PLAN)

**"PO LIST NO" column :** getting from A table (PURCHASE_ORDER)

**"PO NO" column :** getting from A table (PURCHASE_ORDER)

**"PLAN QTY" column :** getting from main table (RECEIVE PLAN)

Comment: I appreciate the visual diagrams and effort, but I think your question would be more clear with just sample inputs and outputs in plain text.

Comment: http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/jeffs/archive/2007/04/03/Conditional-Joins.aspx

Comment: @ThanapipatPacharatanakoson, please use plain text instead of images. Better yet, post a create table script and insert statements.

Comment: +1 from me. I actually liked the images very much. It helps a lot to visualize things. Of course it's complementary to the text description (in order to copy and paste)

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
SELECT A_TABLE.PO_LIST_NO, A_TABLE.PO_NO, SUM(MAIN_TABLE.PLAN_QTY) FROM A_TABLE
INNER JOIN B_TABLE ON A_TABLE.PO_ID = B_TABLE.PO_ID
INNER JOIN MAIN_TABLE ON MAIN_TABLE.PO_ID = B_TABLE.PO_ID OR MAIN_TABLE.RS_ID = B_TABLE.RS_ID
WHERE (MAIN_TABLE.RS_ID IS NOT NULL OR MAIN_TABLE.PO_ID IS NOT NULL) AND NOT (MAIN_TABLE.RS_ID IS NOT NULL AND MAIN_TABLE.PO_ID IS NOT NULL) 
GROUP BY A_TABLE.PO_LIST_NO, A_TABLE.PO_NO
```

Answer (score 1):

I can solved it by using this query.

```
( SELECT   MAIN_TABLE.*,   A_TABLE.PO_LIST_NO, A_TABLE.PO_NO
  FROM          MAIN_TABLE  
                LEFT OUTER JOIN A_TABLE
                ON MAIN_TABLE.PO_ID = A_TABLE.TRAN_ID
  WHERE  (MAIN_TABLE.RS_ID IS NULL) 
)  

  UNION 


( SELECT     MAIN_TABLE.*   , A_TABLE.PO_LIST_NO , A_TABLE.PO_NO
  FROM          MAIN_TABLE  
                LEFT OUTER JOIN B_TABLE 
                ON MAIN_TABLE.RS_ID = B_TABLE .TRAN_ID
                             LEFT OUTER JOIN A_TABLE  
                             ON B_TABLE .PO_ID = A_TABLE.TRAN_ID
  WHERE      (MAIN_TABLE.PO_ID IS NULL)  
 )
```

Comment: You are a genius! Simple and effective solution!